# Filter out multiple row based on conditions

Tags: sql

im new in sql.i have a query which generates below results

```
DOCNUM   USER   STATUS
------   -----  ------
10001    A1     PENDING
10001    A2     APPROVED
10001    A3     PENDING
10002    B1     PENDING
10002    B2     PENDING
10002    B3     PENDING
```

I need to filter out only Pending rows based on docnum, where as above example, docnum 10001 have 3 rows,but has one of the rows approved,therefore i dont need to capture all this 3 rows. As for Docnum 10002, all 3 rows still pending so i need to capture it.
Any idea on how i may filter it out on the query selection?Thanks alot

Comment: tag the _RDBMS_ you are targetting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you mean.
Something like

```
select *
from yourtable
where status = 'PENDING'
```

?

OK, from your comment I now understand what you mean. Try this:

```
select *
  from yourtable t1
 where not exists (
       select 1
         from yourtable t2
        where t1.docnum = t2.docnum
          and t2.status != 'PENDING'
  )
```

To explain how it works:
The inner query selects all documents that have an APPROVED state somewhere. If this set is empty for some document, all the states must be PENDING

Comment: Hi ronald, i cant filter by the status as i need it to link to the docnum.

Comment: What do you mean with "link it to the docnum"? Something like `select * from yourtable where status = 'PENDING' and docnum = '12345'` ? (or without quotes of course if docnum is defined to be numeric)

Comment: Hi ronald, one document number can have multiple rows which is generated by different users but each document can only have 2 status, either 'pending' or 'approved', So for report purpose, i just want to grab those documents which have all of it rows without any approved status,with those already having at least a single row 'approved' to be filtered out.

Comment: Good answer, but I think you mean 

`select * from yourtable t1
   where not exists (
       select 1 from yourtable t2
       where t1.docnum = t2.docnum
       and t2.status != 'PENDING'
   )`

Comment: Thanks AL and Ronald.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find the "count of pending documents" for each docnum then the following should suffice:

```
SELECT docnum, count(1) FROM `table` where Status = 'PENDING' GROUP BY Docnum;
```

If you just want to find all those entries that are pending, then the answer provided by @Ronald above will be just the job.

If you want do select the pending rows by a PENDING status for a SPECIFIED docnum you can do the following:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` where Status = 'PENDING' AND Docnum = '10001';
```

Cheers